# Change the child(grandchild) class when tab is active

Tags: javascript, python, html, tabs

I have looked around on google and on this forum but I can't find what I need, or I don't know how to apply it on my code.

What I try to accomplish is to change the icons when the tab is selected(highlight it).For the icons I used sprite img and the {{ icon }} is a list with icon's names.

Html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-icons" role ="tablist">
  {% for icon in icon_list1 %}
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a href="#{{icon}}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{icon}}" data-toggle="pill" aria-expanded="false">
       <div class="icon-{{icon}}"></div>
     </a>
   </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

- I have this code 3 times on my page with different icon_list for different sections.
  and I would like when the page is loaded the first item to in the each list to be active and highlighted(red icon)

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.nav.nav-icons .nav-item:first-child').addClass('active');
    $('.nav-item').find('div').toggleClass(function(){
        var className = $(this).attr('class');          
        var classRed = className + '-red';          
        if ( $( this ).parents().is( ".active" ) ) {            
            return classRed ;               
        }else{      
            return className;

        }
    });
 });
```

so here when the li elem is active div class is changed from 'icon-name' to 'icon-name-red' and when another tab is selected, same thing but the previous div class to be changed back to 'icon-name'. The thing is when I add the click event I have to click twice for something to happen.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did found a way to fix my problem, so maybe this will help anyone.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //activate the first item in the list
    $('.nav.nav-icons .nav-item:first-child').addClass('active');   
    $('.nav-item.active').find("div").attr('class',function(i, v) {
        return v.replace('-white', '-red');
    });         
});
 //this code is for each icon_list
$(function(){        
   $('.nav-item.list1').unbind('click');
   $('.nav-item.list1').on('click',
     function(){    
       $(this).toggleClass('active');                   
       if ( $( this ).hasClass('active')){  
          $('.nav-item.list1 ').find("div").attr('class',function(i, v) {
            return v.replace('-red', '-white');
          });               
          $(this).find("div").attr('class',function(i, v) {
            return v.replace('-white', '-red');
          });
      }
      $(this).toggleClass('active');    
   });
```

I just hope someone has a better solution or maybe some ideas to improve mine.